# in a lattice, does the GLB and LUB of each element need to be contained in the lattice itself?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, definition

I'm confused about this [definition on wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lattice_(order)).
[image]
Do the GLB and LUB need to be contained in $L$ for it to be a lattice?

if they must be contained, what's the GLB or LUB of two elements $(x,y) \in L$ where $x$ is the LUB or GLB of $L$ itself and happens to be incomparable with $y$? wouldn't the result of that operation need to be outside $L$ if it were to exist? does that mean it's not a lattice?

If the result can't be contained in $L$ then it needs to be outside of $L$, then I guess I would need to define some superset of $L$ that has the same operations as $L$ for the GLB and LUB to live on? in that case is this still a lattice?

The [definition on wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lattice_(order)) says nothing about this.

Let me know if any clarification is needed.

Comment: Yes, the GLB and LUB must be in the lattice. If $x$ is the LUB of $L$, then $x$ cannot be incomparable with $y$ - by definition of LUB you must have $x \geq y$. Similarly if $x$ is the GLB of $L$.

Comment: you are right!, So for a lattice, you would need $\forall x,y \in L: \exists x \land y \in L, \exists x \lor y \in L $

where $\land \lor$ are GLB, LUB.

Is it mandatory for a lattice then that at some point for some $x \in L$ it must happen that $x \land y = x$ for example?  it feels like a must if all GLBs and LUBs must be in $L$

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. $x \wedge x=x$ always, so what conditions are you imposing on $y$?

Comment: sorry, let me try to clarify, I'm asking if as a result of the definition of lattice , it will hold that for any lattice $L$ there will be at least 2 elements (GLB and LUB of $L$ which I will call $g$ and $l$) for which for any member $x \in L$ it will hold that $g \land x = g$ and $l \lor x = l$. thanks for your patience!.

Comment: Oh, certainly not. Those are usually called $0$ and $1$ in a lattice ($0$ is the GLB and $1$ is the LUB), but they need not exist. For instance, the integers are a lattice with the usual ordering, but there is no least or greatest integer. A finite lattice will have a $0$ and $1$.

Comment: aha!, yeah i realized that just a second ago while looking a few examples of lattices on wikipedia and i say exactly that, the lattice of integers!, so would my statement be true for finite lattices?

Comment: Yes, a finite lattice always has a $0$ and a $1$.

Comment: does that mean that 0 and 1 are also complements of any finite lattice then?
since $\forall x: x \lor 0 = 0$ and $x \land 1 = 1$
using the definition of complements from wiki https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complemented_lattice

Comment: Yes, that's true.